# 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error with Kathara, Docker and iptables/nftables

Tags: mac, iptables, docker, nftables

I want to use [Kathara](https://www.kathara.org/) via "[kathara lstart](https://www.kathara.org/man-pages/kathara-lstart.1.html)" but I get a `500 Server Error: Internal Server Error` and I don't understand why. I'm using Docker (Preview version for Apple M1). I don't know if the M1 chip is the problem.

The full error message is:

`500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("NetworkDriver.CreateNetwork:  (iptables failed: iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i kt-c78f8c96291e -o kt-c78f8c96291e -j ACCEPT: iptables/1.8.2 Failed to initialize nft: Protocol family not supported (exit status 1))")`

Thank you for your answer.

*Terminal Error (Screenshot)*
[image: Terminal error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iptables/1.8.2 Failed to initialize nft: Protocol not supported](https://superuser.com/questions/1480986/iptables-1-8-2-failed-to-initialize-nft-protocol-not-supported)

Comment: I can neither use "iptables" nor "nftables"

Comment: Your question clearly quotes iptables is involved in the error. Perhaps your problem is misidentified if you cannot use iptables. You should probably work to fix that problem first.